# Mysql: joining tables for translation records

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables with this configuration:

```
table language('id', 'language_name', 'iso_code')
table translation('id', 'language_id', 'translated_text')
```

In the first table I have records:

```
---------------------------------
| id | language_name | iso_code |
---------------------------------
| 1  | English       | en       |
| 2  | Espanõl       | es       |
| 3  | Français      | fr       |
---------------------------------
```

The second table:

```
--------------------------------------
| id | language_id | translated_text |
--------------------------------------
| 1  | 1           | Good Morning    |
| 2  | 1           | How are you?    |
| 1  | 2           | Buenos dias     |
| 2  | 3           | Comment ça va?  |
--------------------------------------
```

All English text strings exist, but some of the other languages dont.

I would like to show a table with ALL English text strings and corresponding translations, like:

```
----------------------------------------
| text_id | en           | es          |
----------------------------------------
| 1       | Good Morning | Buenos dias |
| 2       | How are you? |             |
----------------------------------------
```

or

```
-------------------------------------------
| text_id | en           | fr             |
-------------------------------------------
| 1       | Good Morning | Comment ça va? |
| 2       | How are you? |                |
-------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any relation between your translations.

Comment: `Good Morning` is `Bon Jour` in french.... `How are you?` is `Comment ca va`. Beyond that, you cannot do this with standard MySQL. You need a pivot table to produce this arbitrary translation table, and mysql doesn't support them (though you can build one easily client-side).

Comment: @Shef: There is a relation, in the id column.

Comment: @MarcB: I don't want to translate strings with mysql, i just want to use translated strings that are in the database. Anyway, DRapp just gave me a solution that seems perfect for me! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep doing left joins to same table on the ID, but extra columns representing their language...

Edited to show English if no value in corresponding columns per comment inquiry.

```
select 
      eng.id,
      eng.translated_text InEnglish,
      coalesce( spn.translated_text, eng.translated_text ) InSpanish,
      coalesce( frn.translated_text, eng.translated_text )  InFrench
   from
      translation eng
         left join translation spn
            on eng.id = spn.id
            and spn.Language_ID = 2
         left join translation frn
            on eng.id = frn.id
            and spn.Language_ID = 3
   where
      eng.Language_id = 1
   order by 
      eng.id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helps. Is there a way to fill in the empty spaces in the other languages with the corresponding English string?

Comment: @thir13en, As a newbie, when you do get a solution, it's generally good practice to click the checkmark next to the answer for your solution.  It helps others looking for similar questions, and also notifies others its solved and you don't get hit with a ton of answers thinking its unsolved.

Comment: @thir13en, See revision with COALESCE()... if the first value doesn't exist, it uses the next...