# mysql query with dynamic return column name

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables,`Products`, `Languages` and `Products_translation`.

How can I retrieve one Product and all translation at same time in one query ?

I have this

```
SELECT p.*, pt.description FROM Products p 
LEFT JOIN Products_translation pt ON p.id=pt.product_id 
LEFT JOIN Languages l ON pt.language =l.code
```

I have 3 languages, but it only retrieves one field name 'description' and I wanted it to return 3 (the number of languages), with something like `description_en, description_es, description_fr`

It's possible to make something like `pt.description AS 'description'+'l.code'` ?

Comment: Please share tables structure

Comment: I have added them

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common question and I'm fairly sure it's been answered many times (for example here: [Mysql: joining tables for translation records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557817/mysql-joining-tables-for-translation-records)). Anyway, if you have only 3 languages, just do this:

```
SELECT p.*, pt_en.description as description_en, pt_es.description as description_es, pt_fr.description as description_fr FROM Products p 
LEFT JOIN Products_translation pt_en ON (p.id=pt.product_id and pt.language = 'en')
LEFT JOIN Products_translation pt_es ON (p.id=pt.product_id and pt.language = 'es')
LEFT JOIN Products_translation pt_fr ON (p.id=pt.product_id and pt.language = 'fr')
```

If you have more than 3, or a varying number, search *pivoting* or *pivot table* for more info. It's not easy to do in SQL so usually it's faster to just select your products, select all the translations of those products in a separate query, and construct the result you want outside of the database.

Comment: Thanks, but what I wanted was to do all in just one query without knowing the values in languages